# Local request's timestamp

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to get local date time when user submitted request to Skype bot?

Asking because it seems that Activity.timestamp which is available at web hook handler - is a timestamp from MS Bot Hub and is always UTC 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons the user's location is not shared with the bot.

Comment: What is the suggested way then to handle a message whose response would depend on the user's timezone?

If a user says, remind me to do X at night, how do you know when it would be night at the user's timezone?